# PHP Prepared Statements Not Updating SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my first time diving into using prepared statements to update MySQL. Not sure where I'm going wrong here, but when I hit the submit button, the page refreshes without any updates actually taking effect.

```
<?php session_start();

include_once("../includes/connection.php");
include_once("../includes/product.php");

$product = new Product;
$products = $product->fetch_all();

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '{$id}'";
    $statement = $pdo->query($sql_select);
    $r = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) { $name = $_POST['product_name']; }
    if (isset($_POST['product_avail'])) { $avail = $_POST['product_avail']; }
    if (isset($_POST['product_price'])) { $price = $_POST['product_price']; }
    if (isset($_POST['product_desc'])) { $desc = $_POST['product_desc']; }
    if (isset($_POST['image'])) { $img = $_POST['image']; }

    $sql_update = 'UPDATE products SET (product_name, product_avail, product_price, product_desc, image) 
    VALUES (:name, :avail, :price, :desc, :img) WHERE product_id = :id';

    $updstmt = $pdo->prepare($sql_update);
    $updstmt->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id,
        ':name' => $name,
        ':avail' => $avail,
        ':price' => $price,
        ':desc' => $desc,
        ':img' => $img));
    }
?>
    <?php include_once("../includes/header.php"); ?>
        <h4>Edit product</h4>
            <!-- call error if any required fields are empty -->
            <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
                <small style="color:#aa0000;">* <?php echo $error; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <form action="edit_test.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post">
                <small>Product Name</small><br />
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $r['product_name']; ?>" <?php if (isset($error) && empty($_POST['product_name'])) { ?> class="error" <?php } ?>/>
                <br /><br />
                <small>Available?</small>
                    <input type="text" name="product_avail" value="<?php echo $r['product_avail']; ?>" <?php if (isset($error) && empty($_POST['product_avail'])) { ?> class="error" <?php } ?>/>
                <small>Price</small>
                &#36;<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $r['product_price']; ?>" <?php if (isset($error) && empty($_POST['product_price'])) { ?> class="error" <?php } ?>/>
                <br /><br />
                <small>Product Description</small>
                    <textarea rows="20" cols="30" name="product_desc" <?php if (isset($error) && empty($_POST['product_desc'])) { ?> class="error" <?php } ?>><?php echo $r['product_desc']; ?>    </textarea><br /><br />
            <br /><br />
                <small>Product Image</small>
                <input type="text" name="image" value="<?php echo $r['image']; ?>" <?php if (isset($error) && empty($_POST['i'])) { ?> class="error" <?php } ?>/>

                <input type="submit" value="POST" class="submit save">
            </form>

            <br /><br />
            <small><a href="index.php">&larr; Back</a></small>
        </div>
    <?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Why are you using prepared statements in other queries, but **NOT** the first `select * from products` query?

Comment: UPDATE doesn't have VALUES, it has SET; second one this week.

Comment: If not update then insert - `UPDATE products SET` to `INSERT INTO products` hard to say what you want to do here.

Comment: They go and write a [whole page on how to use `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) and nobody bothers to read it. **Bookmark the MySQL documentation** until you know it inside and out.

Comment: @MarcB - thanks for pointing that out. Again, I'm pretty new to all of this. I will fix that part. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conjunction with Jay's answer:

It's because of this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` yet your submit button isn't named.

```
<input type="submit" value="POST" class="submit save">
```

so change it to

```
<input type="submit" value="POST" class="submit save" name="submit">
```

Your conditional statement depends on it and nothing inside that statement will execute because of it.

However, if not update then do and insert by changing `UPDATE products SET` to `INSERT INTO products`, if you want to indeed INSERT and not UPDATE.

---

Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to catch errors.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks Jay. It just seemed troubling that in conjunction with your given answer, the code wasn't working so I immediately checked the conditional statements and POST variables, and form elements. I'm glad this one got solved, *cheers*

Comment: I had been over it several times and didn't see it. Teamwork FTW!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Team work indeed and it works rather well :) Anything for the greater good ;)

Comment: Now if I can figure out a way to make the form values update after being saved without having to refresh the page.

Comment: @danbeer Try using a header to redirect to the same page, or use Ajax.

Comment: AJAX @danbeer - I'd use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You'll be looking at modularizing your code at that point too - HTML in one file, PHP in another with JavaScript / jQuery in yet another. Sounds like I another blog, huh Fred?

Answer (score 5):

Your `UPDATE` statement is wrong. It shouldn't use `VALUES`.

```
$sql_update = 'UPDATE products SET product_name = :name, product_avail = :avail, product_price = :price, product_desc = :desc, image = :img WHERE product_id = :id';
```

Adding error checking to you page and to your SQL statements would have revealed that your query was wrong. *Always* code with error checking turned on and code to remove errors.

Comment: Yessir. They seem to come in waves.

Comment: I'll bet they all go to the same place for drinks. *hic!*

Comment: I modified the code to reflect your changes, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I will add some error checking to the page to see what that finds.

Comment: At least the UPDATE query is fixed :)

Comment: At the very least, thank you for that, Jay. And I'll have Fred-ii- know that I've never consumed alcohol in my life, but thanks for playing.

Comment: @danbeer I was just kidding. You'll get to know me after a while ;) oh and I don't neither, *strangely enough*.

Comment: And yet you have 'beer' in your name @danbeer :) And yeah, you can ignore Freddo on stuff like this. He gets a little weird in the afternoon.

Comment: ...but mostly at night and the full moon's coming up too, *woohoo!* I mean... *Aaaahhh oouuuuhhh*

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's kind of pricey to change a last name. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I would have changed mine to 'scotch'.

Comment: @danbeer Kinda pricey, yea... especially at what beer sells for nowadays. Oh, and they give you a free Tshirt inside very case, oh wow! If only they'd do that for every pound of coffee beans I buy, I'd have a full wardrobe! Now, if they'd only could fit in a pair of Italian shoes; yeah I know... no room.

Comment: @danbeer I think I figured it out (in conjunction with Jay's answer), this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` yet your submit button isn't named `<input type="submit" value="POST" class="submit save">` so change it to `<input type="submit" value="POST" class="submit save" name="submit">` - your conditional statement depends on it and nothing inside that statement will execute because of it. Shall I make that an "answer"? If Jay will let me lol

Comment: You wonderful human being, you! God, what a silly mistake to make! That plus Jay's fix worked! I owe you both at least two or three beers!

Comment: Yes - make it an answer @Fred-ii- Better to be totally correct *when we can*. ;)

Comment: True. I've posted one below Jay. Glad we got this resolved. Another team effort, cheers!

Comment: @danbeer You're most welcome Dan, I'm glad we got this matter resolved. Make mine a double Espresso.